# Form button disabled when all form controls have valid values

Tags: angular, forms, validation

I built an angular reactive form with 4 form controls.
3 of them are valid but one of them is failing the validation check (narrowed it down to it the form control called Tz) and I can't figure out why.
This is what the custom validator I built for it looks like for it:

```
const tzAsyncValidator = (http: HttpClient) => (c: FormControl)=>{
  console.log(c.parent);
  if (!c|| String (c.value).length ===0){
    return of(null);
  }
  return http.get('http://localhost:4000/userIds/'+ String (c.value))
  .pipe(
    debounceTime(500),
    map((ids:any[])=>{
      console.log(ids);
      if (ids.length===1){

        return {exists:true}
      }
      if (ids.length===0){

        return {exists:null};
      }
    }),
  );
}
```

(It takes the field input and sends it as a parameter to the server to check if the ID exists, if it exists, then it is bad and a proper error is displayed:

```
<span *ngIf="newUser.get('Tz').errors?.exists">This ID already exists</span>
```

If it doesn't exist, no error is displayed, the status of the form control should turn into valid and in turn, turn the whole formgroup status into valid but it remains invalid still.
This is what it looks like:

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import {matchOtherValidator} from '../match-other-validator';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import {map,debounceTime} from 'rxjs/operators';

const tzAsyncValidator = (http: HttpClient) => (c: FormControl)=>{
  console.log(c.parent);
  if (!c|| String (c.value).length ===0){
    return of(null);
  }
  return http.get('http://localhost:4000/userIds/'+ String (c.value))
  .pipe(
    debounceTime(500),
    map((ids:any[])=>{
      console.log(ids);
      if (ids.length===1){

        return {exists:true}
      }
      if (ids.length===0){

        return {exists:null};
      }
    }),
  );
}



@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.component.css']
})

export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit { 
  public newUser;
  public verification;
  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }



  ngOnInit() {
    this.newUser = new FormGroup({
      Tz: new FormControl ('',[Validators.required,Validators.minLength(4),Validators.maxLength(9)],[tzAsyncValidator(this.http)]),
      Email: new FormControl ('',[Validators.required,Validators.email]),
      PW: new FormControl ('', [Validators.required,Validators.pattern('^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$')]),
      PWVerification: new FormControl ('', [Validators.required,Validators.pattern('^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$'),matchOtherValidator('PW')])
    })


  }
  onSubmit() {

  }
}
```

and the angular html side:

```
                <form [formGroup]="newUser" (ngSubmit)='onSubmit()' >
                        <label>ID</label>
                        <br>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Please Enter Your ID" formControlName="Tz">
                        <br>
                        <label>Email</label>
                        <br>
                        <input type="email" placeholder="Please Enter Your Email" formControlName="Email">
                        <br>
                        <label>Password</label>
                        <br>
                        <input type="text" name="password" placeholder="Please Choose A Password" formControlName="PW" size="25">
                        <br>
                        <label>Resubmit Your Password</label>
                        <br>
                        <input type="text" name="confirmPassword" placeholder="Please Resubmit Your Password" formControlName="PWVerification" validateEqual="password" size="30" >
                        <br>
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" [disabled]="!newUser.valid" >
                        <br>
                        <span *ngIf="newUser.get('Email').invalid &&!newUser.get('Email').pristine">Your email does not look right</span>
                        <br>
                        <span *ngIf="newUser.get('Tz').errors?.minlength">Your ID must be at least 4 digits long</span>
                        <br>
                        <span *ngIf="newUser.get('Tz').errors?.maxlength">The maximum ID length is 9 digits</span>
                        <br>
                        <span *ngIf="newUser.get('PW').invalid&&!newUser.get('PW').pristine">Password must include at least one letter and one digit</span>
                        <br>
                        <span *ngIf="newUser.get('PWVerification').errors?.matchOther">Your submitted passwords don't match</span>
                        <br>
                        <span *ngIf="newUser.get('Tz').errors?.exists">This ID already exists</span>    
                      </form>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can not create an async validator.

Comment: What does that mean? the third parameter of every formcontrol is used for async validators. Of course you can, unless I didn't understand you properly

Comment: provide stackblitz that will be easy to understand

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ns14bo